# Create NSManagedObject subclass creating classes named as my project

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

I just started having this problem all of a sudden and am very confused as to what is happening.

When I use the option under Editor to Create NSManagedObject subclass it is now just creating files and classes named as my project. It doesn't appear to matter what entities I have chosen to subclass, or how many, it just keeps creating the same exact broken files and classes each time.

Just before this started happening I tried selecting my xcdatamodeld file and in the File Inspector changed its name. It is possible that this caused problems as it hasn't been the same since, even after changing it back.

Any ideas what has happened and more importantly how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out. These classes had previously had subclasses made and I had set their class property in the Data Model inspector. Seems this was messing with the creation process. Even when deleting the previous entry here, it saved out to file as a blank string whereas before it was set it would just save out without the property whatsoever.

I opened the contents of the xcdatamodeld file in a text editor and manually removed all of these empty strings being stored, re-opened my project in Xcode, and then I was able to create the subclasses properly again.